# Prevent drop of list item in JqueryUI sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists  `#sortable1` and `#sortable 2` which are connected sortables, as shown in this [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists).

You can drag and drop list items from `sortable1` to `sortable 2`. However, if an item in **sortable 1** contains the class "number", I want to **prevent** the drop on **Sortable2** and thus make the dragged item drop back into **sortable 1**.

I have used the following on sortable2:

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).hasClass("number")) {
                $(ui.item).remove();
            }
```

but it deletes the list item from both tables altogether. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `stop` and `sortable('cancel')` methods to validate the item being moved. In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/pbs7xwke/), upon an item being dropped, I check if the item is valid by:

1. Checking if the item has the class `number`
2. *and* checking if the list item was dropped in `list2`

This is slightly more hard-coded that I'd like, so alternatively what you could do is check the parent of the dropped item against `this`, to check if the lists are different. This means that you could potentially have an item of `number` in `list1` and `list2`, but they're not interchangeable.

### [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pbs7xwke/)

```
$(function() {
    $('ul').sortable({
        connectWith: 'ul',
        stop: function(ev, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).hasClass('number') && $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] != this) {
                $(this).sortable('cancel');
            }
        }
    });        
});​
```

Comment: Using this method, I seem to get JS errors.  I've updated a bug report on the jQUI site that may be related.  http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4904?cnum_edit=9#comment:9

Comment: cancel is only reliable in the `stop` and `receive` events as mentioned in [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24723176/133717)

Comment: this.sortable didn't works for me, but when changin to ui.sender.sortable("cancel"); id works perfectly

Comment: Getting an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null. It breaks the sortable...

Comment: @Mr.Jo I have updated the above example to hopefully resolve the error.

Answer (score 31):

For anyone reading this in future, as mentioned by [briansol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1981678/briansol) in comments for the accepted answer, it throws error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
```

The the documentation particularly says

> [`cancel()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel)
>
> Cancels a change in the current sortable and reverts it to the state prior to when the current sort was started. Useful in the **stop** and **receive** callback functions.

Canceling the sort during other events is unreliable, So it's better use the [`receive`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event as shown in [Mj Azani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2912502/mj-azani)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548808/2333214) or use the [`stop`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) event as follows:

```
$('#list1').sortable({
  connectWith: 'ul',
  stop: function(ev, ui) {
    if(ui.item.hasClass("number"))
      $(this).sortable("cancel");
   }
}); 

$('#list2').sortable({
   connectWith: 'ul',
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FTm96/)

Answer (score 14):

Try [this example](http://codepen.io/mj_azani/pen/npohF)

```
$('#list1').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul'
});    
    
$('#list2').sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul',
    receive: function(ev, ui) {
        if(ui.item.hasClass("number"))
          ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few experiments, I've found that by far the easiest method is to use the remove event, that essentially only fires when you try to drop an item into a new sortable (that was previously made available as a target using connectWith).

Simply add this to your sortable call:

```
remove:function(e,ui) {
    if(ui.item.hasClass('your_restricted_classname')) return false;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to be able to drag the items with class "number" at all, you can also restrict the whole drag-and-drop functionality to items that don't have the class "number":

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    items: "li:not(.number)"
});
```

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/60gwjsgb/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeStop: function(ev, ui) {
                if ($(ui.item).hasClass('number') && 
                    $(ui.placeholder).parent()[0] != this) {
                    $(this).sortable('cancel');
                }
            }
```

try this.

Answer (score 0):

If a) you only have just these 2 lists, and b) you don't care that your "number" actually be dragged and then drop back, you can simply prevent it from getting dragged by this:

```
 sort: function(event, ui) {
if(ui.item.hasClass('number')) return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 2 cents.
If you don't wish to allow sorting in one of the connected list you can remove it from the containers in the instance object when start even is triggered, so the sorting won't happen at all, and if you need to restore the sorting functionality afterwards, you can recreate the sortable once again or add back removed elements in container array. It would look like this:

```
    start: function(e, ui){
        if(ui.item.hasClass('uniqToSortableItem')){
            var instance = $(this).sortable( "instance" );
            var newContainers = [];
            instance.containers.forEach((el)=> {
                if(!el.element.hasClass('sortableToDisable')){
                    newContainers.push(el);
                } 
            });
            // in case you need to save initial array just attach it to ui.helper
            ui.helper.initialContainersArray = instance.containers;
            instance.containers = newContainers;
        }
    },
    stop: function(e, ui){
        // returning containers array to previous state if necessary
        if(ui.helper.initialContainersArray){
            $(this).sortable( "instance" ).containers = ui.helper.initialContainersArray;
        }
    }
```