# jQuery UI sortable: How to exclude items from connected lists?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists (left/right coloumn) which are connected, so I can drag&drop items from one column (left) to the other (right).

How can I exclude specific items from list1 (left) that should NOT be draggable to list2 (right) **while keeping the functionality to drag&drop them inside their source-list**?

Fiddle:
http://goo.gl/7ZKfrl

Comment: did you try this? $(this).draggable({ disabled: true }) with specifying your condition! Look at disabled under options link http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: See my edit: Dragging inside the source list should further be possible - I just want to prevent the item from beeing dragged to the other list.

Comment: You can check your item text== "test" or value == "1"  assign disabled: true

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent drop of list item in JqueryUI sortable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777438/prevent-drop-of-list-item-in-jqueryui-sortable)

Answer (score 0):

I used the following and it worked for me. Had same requirement.

```
$("ul#YourLeftListID li").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == 'None') {
                $(this).draggable({ disabled: true })
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But after this you can't move the item at all. It should stay movable insdie it's source list (left).

Comment: For that scenario you have to use http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement see the last box which is draggable only in its parent div. Also, it would be helpful if you can create fiddle for this.

Comment: I don't want to restrict the movement itself .. I basically want to restrict the drop-targets. I created a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/ovcz6c4d/2/

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777438/prevent-drop-of-list-item-in-jqueryui-sortable. hope that will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, this reference solved my problem. See it in action here http://www.klamm.de :)