# jquery ui sortable connecwith by children type

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I don't know how to solve this issue:

I have an 3 types of containers:

1.- **.global_container**: children can be: .zona_completa, .zona_izquierda, .zona_derecha

2.- **global_container_2col**: children only can be: .zona_izquierda

3.- **global_container_1col**: children only can be: .zona_derecha

I should move from "global_container_2col" and "global_container_1col" to "global_container"

But I should ONLY move from "global_container" to "container_container_2col" if the item is ".zona_izquierda"

and

I should ONLY move from "global_container" to "container_container_1col" if the item is ".zona_derecha".

HTML:

```
<div class="global_container_2col" data-type="global_container">
  <div class="zona_izquierda zone" data-type="zone">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="global_container_1col" data-type="global_container">
  <div class="zona_derecha zone" data-type="zone">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="global_container" data-type="global_container">
  <div class="zona_izquierda zone" data-type="zone">
  </div>
  <div class="zona_derecha zone" data-type="zone">
  </div>
  <div class="zona_completa zone" data-type="zone">
  </div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('body').sortable(
{
  items: 'div[data-type="global_container"]'
});

$('.global_container').sortable(
{
    connectWith: 'div[data-type="global_container"]',
  items: 'div[data-type="zone"]'
});

$('.global_container_2col').sortable(
{
    connectWith: '.global_container_2col, .global_container',
  items: '.zona_izquierda'
});

$('.global_container_1col').sortable(
{
    connectWith: '.global_container_1col, .global_container',
  items: '.zona_derecha'
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/kwrx4182/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing in this answer:
[Prevent drop of list item in JqueryUI sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777438/prevent-drop-of-list-item-in-jqueryui-sortable/19548808#19548808)

We need to use the "receive" event in the sortable, check the class of the item that is dragged and revert the event:

```
$('body').sortable(
{
  items: 'div[data-type="global_container"]'
});

$('.global_container').sortable(
{
  connectWith: 'div[data-type="global_container"]',
  items: 'div[data-type="zone"]'
});

$('.global_container_2col').sortable(
{
  connectWith: '.global_container_2col, .global_container',
  items: '.zona_izquierda',
  receive: function(ev, ui)
  {
      if(!ui.item.hasClass('zona_izquierda'))
      {
        ui.sender.sortable('cancel');
      }
  }
});

$('.global_container_1col').sortable(
{
  connectWith: '.global_container_1col, .global_container',
  items: '.zona_derecha',
  receive: function(ev, ui)
  {
      if(!ui.item.hasClass('zona_derecha'))
      {
        ui.sender.sortable('cancel');
      }
  }  
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/kwrx4182/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.global_container_2col').sortable(
{
    connectWith: '.global_container_2col, .global_container',
  items: '.zona_izquierda',
  items: 'div:not(.zona_derecha)'
});

$('.global_container_1col').sortable(
{
    connectWith: '.global_container_1col, .global_container',
  items: '.zona_derecha'
  ,items: 'div:not(.zona_izquierda)'
});
```